# DocuSign API Integration Problems

Tags: docusignapi

I have created sandbox using https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/ and able to generate integrator key and private/public key.

I have downloded https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt code and configure key as per given instruction.

It's giving me error like 
"com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting an access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 0):

For code example

[eg-01-java-jwt](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt), you need to add the suffix `\n\` after each line in the config.properties file. See the comments in the [config.properties](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt/blob/master/src/main/resources/config.properties) file.

Don't add a " or other characters.